# Wordpress mail send but my domain doesnt recieve

Tags: php, html, wordpress, email

I have a website developed in WordPress, it have contact form 7 for contact but also tryig with lot of plugins that worked fine. Its sending message successfully but not receiving email.

I am not receiving mail on same domain (bla@domain.com) but receiving on other email (my@gmail.com, my@yahoo.com). Why it is happening? any guess or clue? Would love some help!

Comment: You can go through the accepted answer for this question: [PHP mail function doesn't complete sending of e-mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-function-doesnt-complete-sending-of-e-mail) - All of the suggestions might not be relevant, but some might. There are many reasons this could happen.

Comment: But it does send the mail, i mean i try using my domain mail (mydomain@domain.com) and gmail acc and my domaing doesnt recibe but my gmail does.

Comment: That's included in that answer. If you're sending the email from the servers local SMTP (like using sendmail and/or PHP's built in mail() function), some servers might block the emails (or mark them as spam) if you haven't set up DKIM or SPF records on the senders domains DNS, allowing your server sending emails using that domain. That's why some might receive the emails and some won't.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use other contact form plugin since many people are complaining and have the same issue as what you are experiencing right now. See https://wordpress.org/support/topic/not-receiving-email-messages-from-contact-form-7/.

If you still want to work with Contact Form 7, you will need to work with your WordPress developer to make sure the settings are correct http://kb.cf7skins.com/contact-form-7-email-issues